# Get the values from any items inside a multiselect in .net

Tags: jquery, asp.net, vb.net, multi-select

I have a simple multiselct dropdownlist control on my page...it gets populated via a Jquery plugin:

When the page runs in the browser i can inspect the element...

```
<select name="ctl00$ctl00$cphMainContent$cpcMainContent$ddlgroups_to" id="ctl00_ctl00_cphMainContent_cpcMainContent_ddlgroups_to" class="input-large" size="8" multiple="multiple">

    <option value="1025">Company Administrators</option><option value="1027">Finance</option><option value="1029">Procurement</option></select>
```

As you can see none of items are selected but I want to get all the items IN this list. Really i should be able to do this...

```
For Each aItem As ListItem In Me.ddlgroups_to.Items
     _employee.Groups.Add(Int32.Parse(aItem.Value))         
Next
```

But i get nothing?

Comment: It is because you are adding them via Jquery. There is no databinding from code behind.

Comment: Cheers, maybe i can grab them via JQ...

Comment: You can also add the employee groups to a HiddenField in csv format and do a string split in code behind: `string[] employeeGroups = HiddenField1.Value.Split(';');`

Comment: Yeah it how and when i get the values from the items i have moved across. HiddenField is the way I am going.